# How to install SignalR via NuGet, Failed to add Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure?

Tags: .net, nuget, signalr, nuget-package

I'm attempting to install SignalR using:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -pre
```

I'm getting an error stating that Nuget cannot add `Microsfot.Web.Infrastructure` reference. Anyone have any idea why this would be? Below is the full output:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -pre
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS (≥ 1.0.0-rc1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'jQuery (≥ 1.6.4)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb (≥ 1.0.0-rc1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin (≥ 1.0.0-rc1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core (≥ 1.0.0-rc1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Newtonsoft.Json (≥ 4.5.4)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Owin (≥ 1.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb (≥ 1.0.0-rc1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure (≥ 1.0.0.0)'.
You are downloading Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core from Microsoft, the license agreement to which is available at http://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/eula/aspnet_and_web_tools_2012_EULA_ENU.htm. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core 1.0.0-rc1'.
Successfully installed 'Owin 1.0'.
You are downloading Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin from Microsoft, the license agreement to which is available at http://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/eula/aspnet_and_web_tools_2012_EULA_ENU.htm. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin 1.0.0-rc1'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0.0'.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core 1.0.0-rc1' to OProject.
Successfully added 'Owin 1.0' to OProject.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin 1.0.0-rc1' to OProject.
Value does not fall within the expected range.
Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0.0'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin 1.0.0-rc1'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Owin 1.0'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core 1.0.0-rc1'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Failed to add reference to 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure'.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -pre
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Comment: Is there a more detailed error message?

Comment: See above... I added the full output from the console.

Comment: uninstall it, update the nuget package and try it again

Comment: It never got installed. If you notice above, it says it was rolled back. I'm not sure what you mean by update the NuGet Package.

Comment: What kind of project are you installing it into?

Comment: I was attempting to install it to an existing web site project, .NET Web Forms.

Comment: Hi Folks.  I'm getting a similar issue, running VS2012, except that my error message is:  install-package : Failed to add reference to 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb'.  (As an aside, this is the second bizarro nuget config bug I've experienced in 2 days.  NuGet is NotGreat).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are running the latest Nuget as well. Are you on VS2012 or VS2010

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  For me, it seemed I already had the directory for the package, but there were no DLL files inside of it.  Here's how I solved it:

1. **Delete your local directory for Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure**, for example:

c:\MySolution\packages\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0

1. **Re-run the installation of the NuGet package** (for example, SignalR).